# XML parent child concatenation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

INPUT XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<system>
<map name="Map">
    <map name="Map1">
        <color>Map1 is red colored</color>
        <shape>Map1 is square shaped</shape>
    </map>
    <map name="Map2">
        <color>Map2 is green colored</color>
        <map name="Tap1">
            <color>Tap1 is yellow colored</color>
            <speed>Tap1 is very fast</speed>
        </map>
        <map name="Tap2">
            <speed>Tap2 is very slow</speed>
        </map>
    </map>
</map>
</system>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<system>
<map name="Map+Map1">
    <color>Map1 is red colored</color>
    <shape>Map1 is square shaped</shape>
</map>
<map name="Map+Map2">
    <color>Map2 is green colored</color>
</map>
<map name="Map+Map2+Tap1">
    <color>Tap1 is yellow colored</color>
    <speed>Tap1 is very fast</speed>
</map>
<map name="Map+Map2+Tap2">
    <speed>Tap2 is very slow</speed>
</map>
```

Current OUTPUT :

```
<system>
    <map name="Map1"/>
    <map name="Map1"/>
    <map name="Map2"/>  
    <map name="Map2.Tap1"/>
    <map name="Map2.Tap1"/>
    <map name="Map2.Tap2"/>
</system>
```

Current XSL Stylesheet :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="map[@name]">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="next">
       <xsl:with-param name="name" select="''" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="map[@name]" mode="next">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="next">
    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="concat($name,'.',@name)" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]" mode="next">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:element name="map">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:variable name="nameLength" select="string-length($name)-1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($name,2,$nameLength)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()|*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am just a beginner in XSL. I referred a lot online and tried to solve this problem.
But i was failed. Somebody please help me to get the right xsl code for achieving the same.
Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="map" mode="concat" >
        <xsl:param name="names" select="''" />
        <xsl:variable name="newName" select="concat($names,@name)" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name ="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$newName"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[name() != 'map']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="map" mode ="concat">
            <xsl:with-param name="names" select="concat($newName,'+')" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="map" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/map">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="map" mode="concat">
            <xsl:with-param name ="names" select="concat(@name,'+')" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this small example the mode my not be necessary but would be helpful if the xlst file grows.
Otuput:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<system>
  <map name="Map+Map1">
    <color>Map1 is red colored</color>
    <shape>Map1 is square shaped</shape>
  </map>
  <map name="Map+Map2">
    <color>Map2 is green colored</color>
  </map>
  <map name="Map+Map2+Tap1">
    <color>Tap1 is yellow colored</color>
    <speed>Tap1 is very fast</speed>
  </map>
  <map name="Map+Map2+Tap2">
    <speed>Tap2 is very slow</speed>
  </map>
</system>
```

Comment: hr_117, if i have a larger XML file with the "system" tag as an inner tag, how can i modify this stylesheet to keep the same output.
With the current XSL stylesheet im not getting the expected output. :(

Comment: Change `<xsl:template match="*" >` to `<xsl:template match="system" >` and  `<xsl:template match="/*/map">` to  `<xsl:template match="system/map">`. Than, how and were to apply the "system" templates depends on the rest of your xslt.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) :)

Sorry, i have one more doubt. what i have to do if i have to rename all those tag named "map" to some other name in the output

Comment: That's also easy. Change  `<xsl:copy>` ... `</xsl:copy>` in `<xsl:template match="map" mode="concat">` to `<some_other_name>`.

Comment: i dont have words to thank you.. :) :) #work.Done
You are a star :D

Comment: <system>    
        <map name="Map">
            <color>Map is black colored</color>
            <map name="Map1">
                <color>Map1 is red colored</color>
                <shape>Map1 is square shaped</shape>
            </map>
            .....
            .....
    </system>
 
Like in the above example if i have a subnode "color" or something for any parent nodes(ie.for any system/map), our current stylesheet is ignoring them. But i have to keep them as they are, in the output XML also.
Can we attain the same by doing some minor modifications in the current stylesheet?

Comment: That could be done by small changes to the `<xsl:template match="system/map">`. Add a copy-of or aplay-template for what you like to have in output. But I think it's time you start understand how  xslt is working

Comment: @hr_117..Mission completed.. :) :D
         You made me a small XSLT developer.
         Learned a lot of things from you within these 2 days :)
         Thank you MASTER :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another 1.0 option...

**XML Input**

```
<map name="Map">
    <map name="Map1">
        <color>Map1 is red colored</color>
        <shape>Map1 is square shaped</shape>
    </map>
    <map name="Map2">
        <color>Map2 is green colored</color>
        <map name="Tap1">
            <color>Tap1 is yellow colored</color>
            <speed>Tap1 is very fast</speed>
        </map>
        <map name="Tap2">
            <speed>Tap2 is very slow</speed>
        </map>
    </map>
</map>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <system><xsl:apply-templates/></system>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map[*[not(self::map)]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::map[@name]">
                    <xsl:if test="ancestor::map[@name]">+</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::map)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="map"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<system>
   <map name="Map+Map1">
      <color>Map1 is red colored</color>
      <shape>Map1 is square shaped</shape>
   </map>
   <map name="Map+Map2">
      <color>Map2 is green colored</color>
   </map>
   <map name="Map+Map2+Tap1">
      <color>Tap1 is yellow colored</color>
      <speed>Tap1 is very fast</speed>
   </map>
   <map name="Map+Map2+Tap2">
      <speed>Tap2 is very slow</speed>
   </map>
</system>
```

Also, if you can use XSLT 2.0, you can replace the `xsl:attribute` with this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="name" select="string-join(ancestor-or-self::map/@name,'+')"/>
```

Comment: Daniel, your code is also working perfect. :)
I accepted the other answer only because it was something similar to what i was thinking of solving the problem.

I tried to vote you up. But they want me to get atleast 15 reputations before doing the same :(

Anyways, from the bottom of my heart, thanx a lot :) :)

Comment: Daniel, I have a doubt. Can you please help me?
Your stylesheet worked for me in all cases.
How can i modify this stylesheet if i have to rename the tag named "map" in the input XML to "mapped" in the output XML?

Comment: @user2441654 - Easy...in the template that matches `map[*[not(self::map)]]` replace the `xsl:copy` with `<mapped>`.